# How can I make sure a Github Workflow can be used by only selected repositories/workflows in my Github Organization?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, github-ci

I've created 2 workflows, one is caller workflow `A` in repository `A` and other is called workflow `B` in repository `B`.
Both the repositories are part of Github Org `OrgName`.
Workflow `B` in repository `B` is intended to be reusable by certain private repositories in my Github Org, not all private repositories.
Github says that all private repositories in an org will get access to a private reusable workflow.
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/sharing-actions-and-workflows-with-your-organization#about-github-actions-access-to-private-repositories

> Any actions or reusable workflows stored in the private repository can
> be used in workflows defined in other private repositories owned by
> the same organization. Actions and reusable workflows stored in
> internal repositories cannot be used in public repositories and
> actions and reusable workflows stored in private repositories cannot
> be used in public or internal repositories.

How can I make sure only selected private repos in my org are able to use this reusable workflow `A`.
Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Whether you share workflows / actions from a user private repository, or a private org repository for other private repositories to access it. It's not possible to select specific repositories(yet?). [Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/enabling-features-for-your-repository/managing-github-actions-settings-for-a-repository#allowing-access-to-components-in-a-private-repository)

Comment: is there any hack or check I can add to make sure only certain repos are able to get access to the reusable workflow?

Comment: The best solution would probably involve a custom API managing the reusable workflow calls. If you can't, an option could be to ask for a PAT or specific KEY as input to your reusable workflow, and only allow PAT / KEY from a specific list of users / repositories in your organization to run the workflow when (through a check job). It may not be enough, but would already gives you control to who can or not use the workflow.